# Display 3 DIVs in a line

Tags: css, html, css-position

I am trying to display 3 divs like a horizontal line.

Like this:

[image]

This is my HTML :

```
         <div class="notactive"></div>
         <div class="notactive"></div>
         <div class="notactive"></div>
```

This is my CSS so far:

```
.notactive {
    height: 10px;
    width: 90px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute; 
    //left: 200px;
    bottom: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    display: block-inline;
}
```

**UPDATE :**

```
.notactive {
    height: 10px;
    width: 90px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute; 
    //left: 200px;
    bottom: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

But I can't get it to work.
Hope someone will help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add a JSFiddle

Comment: No need to float them if you use inline-block! (and you cannot use // to comment a line, it's /* ...code... */

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few problems:

- it's `inline-block` not `block-inline`
- `position:absolute`, `left`, `bottom` is unnecessary
- You were using white as that background for it so you might not have been able to see it

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGKWK/)

```
.notactive {
    height: 10px;
    width: 90px;
    background: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

There is another method using `float:left;` but `inline-block` is sufficient for your needs.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcBz6/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="notactive"></div>
<div class="notactive"></div>
<div class="notactive"></div>
<div class="clear></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.notactive {
    height: 10px;
    width: 90px;
    background: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    float:left;
    margin:2px;
}
```

**EDIT:** [Here is a fix](http://jsfiddle.net/qNXHf/2/) to your problem on the fiddle you put in comments. I wrapped the image and name in a `div` with a fixed `height`. That pushed them down.

Comment: It will never work with position:absolute on 3 siblings as they will all position in the exact same place. Why do you say you need to use it?

Comment: My active slide should highlight with its background color. See my attached image.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your code - it should be

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use absolute position for this, try this:

```
.notactive {
    height: 10px;
    width: 90px;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes display: inline-block is your best option.
Remove absolute positioning unless there is a specific reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.notactive:nth-child(1){left:0px;}
.notactive:nth-child(2){left:100px;}
.notactive:nth-child(3){left:200px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.left
{
width:33%;
background-color:cyan;
float:left;
height:200px;
}
.centre
{
background-color:red;
width:33%;
float:left;
height:200px;
}
.right
{
width:33%;
background-color:cyan;
float:left;
height:200px;
}

</style>
<body>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="centre"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</body>
</html>
try this coding that I have Created for you
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.notactive1
{
 height: 10px;
 width: 90px;
 background: Red;
 position: absolute; 
 top:10px;
 left:100px;
}
.notactive2
{
 height: 10px;
 width: 90px;
 background: Red;
 position: absolute; 
 top:10px;
 left:200px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.notactive3
{
 height: 10px;
 width: 90px;
 background: Red;
 position: absolute; 
 top:10px;
 left:300px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="notactive1"></div>
<div class="notactive2"></div>
<div class="notactive3"></div>
</body>
</html>
Another Answer Hope You Statisfied by this ans......
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;">DIV 1</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:green;">DIV 2</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:blue;">DIV 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, extend tour answer with explanation of what is done with this code.